# How to copy dependencies to gae war/WEB-INF/lib? (take 2)

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-2, dependencies

Have same challenge as this guy:
[How to copy dependencies to gae war/WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421826/how-to-copy-dependencies-to-gae-war-web-inf-lib)

Applying his solution's pom segment for copy-dependencies and running "mvn package" did nothing.  Seems that the goal doesn't ever get run.

Help!

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproj</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
  <!-- <packaging>war</packaging> -->
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myproj</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <!-- Copy dependencies to war/WEB-INF/lib for GAE proj compliance. -->
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/</outputDirectory>
                  <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                  <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                  <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                  <excludeArtifactIds>gwt-user,gwt-dev</excludeArtifactIds>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.6</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
      <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
      <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.8</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7-20060614</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7-20060614</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.9</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.java.dev.rome</groupId>
      <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.java.dev.rome</groupId>
      <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring-library*.libd not avail -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.11</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.11</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
      <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Objectify isn't in a repository, ref it locally -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>spring-objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/objectify-2.2.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>spring-objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/objectify-2.2.1-sources.jar</systemPath>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>spring-objectify-spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/objectify-spring-1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GAE dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>google-appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-sdk-1.3.7</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>C:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.7_1.3.7.v201008311427\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.7\lib\user\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.3.7.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>google-datanucleus-jpa</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>C:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.7_1.3.7.v201008311427\appengine-java-sdk-1.3.7\lib\user\orm\datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <!-- Maven repositories for downloading various artifacts -->
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

Output:

```
C:\myproj\>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproj
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[WARNING] While downloading xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2
  This artifact has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2.


[WARNING] While downloading xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2
  This artifact has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2.


[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [surefire:test]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\myproj\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.myproj.rest.control.TestController
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] [jar:jar]
[INFO] Building jar: C:\myproj\target\myproj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 11 15:04:29 EDT 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/127M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

[How to copy dependencies to gae war/WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421826/how-to-copy-dependencies-to-gae-war-web-inf-lib/3909756#3909756)